# Jenkins Team Foundation Server Plugin and build

Tags: jenkins, azure-devops, jenkins-plugins, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I'm trying to configure Jenkins Team Foundation Server Plugin to our cloud VSTS server . 
used Personal access for authenticationtokens gave all scope.

the test in TFS/Team Services show: Success via SOAP API .
but when I start the

build I get : Query returned no result!

I guess this might be related with project path because as i said the test in TFS/Team Services show: Success via SOAP API .

this is how I enter the urls :

Collection URL : https://projectdev.visualstudio.com/

Project path : `$/project.Generics/project.Generic`

got the project path from `VSTS -> Code -> Files`

tried adding / DefaultCollection didn't help too

what am I missing? 
your help will be appreciated!

Comment: How do you configure it? Check this screenshot: https://1drv.ms/i/s!AresBGZVYryjhTn-qql2TGu3lwMv

Answer (score 0):

[Team Foundation Server Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Team+Foundation+Server+Plugin) can integrate TFS/VSTS source sontrol (Git or TFVC) in jenkins Job, and trigger TFS/VSTS release (not VSTS build).

Details you can find in [tfs-plugin README](https://github.com/jenkinsci/tfs-plugin/blob/master/README.md):

> This plugin integrates Team Foundation Version Control (also known as
>   TFVC) and Git to Jenkins by connecting to Team Foundation Server (TFS)
>   and Visual Studio Team Services (Team Services). It also lets you
>   trigger a release in Visual Studio Team Services, through a post-build
>   step in Jenkins.

Comment: This is exactly what im trying to configure

Comment: @alex So can you show the detail configurations? And what do you mean "when i start the build i get : Query returned no result!"?

Comment: @alex what's your jenkins job configuration?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by configuration ? I'm trying to execute the build . I'll try to upload screen shot in a bit

Comment: Configure for your jenkins job. Especially for the **Source Code Management** part https://imgur.com/a/LDIqn and the **Build** steps part https://imgur.com/a/6KrhS.

Answer (score 0):

The "collection URL" looks correct to me.

The "Project path" should be "$/{Project}/{FolderPath}".

In your case, is your project named "project.Generics" and "project.Generic" is a folder in the project?